# Storing cost between nodes

Tags: c++, search, vector, matrix, nodes

I am making a maze solver using Uniform Cost Search and basically what I want to do is store random costs between rooms in my maze.

Data structure of rooms (named cells):

```
struct Cell
    {
        int row;
        int column;
        vector<Cell*> neighbors;
        State state;
    };
```

row and column are the position in the maze vector of the Cell, the `vector<Cell*> neighbors` defines with which cells this particular cell is connected to and state keeps a state of the cell (visited, empty etc.).

What I tried doing is making a property of the Cell struct like this: `vector<int> cost` where every element of that array matches the neighbor element.

For example:

```
  012345
0 ######
1 #   ##
2 # #  #
3 ######
```

maze[1][1] has in it's neighbors vector:

```
neighbors[0] = *maze[1][2];
neighbors[1] = *maze[2][1];
```

it's cost vector now is:

```
cost[0] = 5;
cost[1] = 10;
```

But that way of doing it created a lot of problems.

What I have thought is that I need a cost matrix which will match one node with another and store the cost in the matrix, something like this:

```
  0  1  2 
0[0][2][4]
1[2][0][6]
2[4][6][0]
```

But in order to do this how will I make my matrix know which cell is which? how instead of 0's and 1's I make it know that it's [0][0] [0][1] [0][2] etc.

Do I need to utilize a 3D vector for something like this? If I do I would prefer to avoid it since I am inexperienced with 3D vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you use a custom object for your link to another room? Eg:

```
struct Cell;

struct CellLink {
  const Cell *cell;
  const int weight;
  ..
};

struct Cell {
  int row;
  int column;
  vector<CellLink> neighbors;
  State state;
};
```

This would keep cost and cell coupled with no worries. Only drawback is that you will store each cost twice (assuming it's symmetric) but this is true in many other approaches (matrix included).

Comment: That looks like it should work, let me try it and I'll get back to you.